# Risk Neutral Valuation, Drifts and Calibration

Tags: derivatives, risk-neutral-measure, pricing, calibration, stochastic-drift

Lets consider a pricing model like Vasicek.

Apparently, if you calibrate a derivatives pricing model to market prices this gives you risk neutral parameters. Its not clear to me as to WHY this will definitely be risk neutral. See here atmif.com/papers/rn.pdf under Market Calibration. "Many authors in the literature simply claim that they are using the "risk neutral" pricing measure when doing market calibrations." How can they just claim this?

If you need your pricing model to be arbitrage free to give a risk neutral measure, then is it just you need model which is arbitrage free and then you just calibrate it to the market and you are done? When you look at the literature, you start with some model of the underlying dynamics and then you apply Girsanov's theorem in order to become risk neutral. Are you calibrating the risk neutral version of your model or the original one to the market?

I thought that for something to be risk neutral it had to drift at the risk free rate $r dt$ (and plus a $\sigma dW$ term). However, derivatives pricing models almost always have non-zero drifts.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Copy of https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/63725/calibrating-derivatives-pricing-models-and-risk-neutral-measures ?

Comment: No its reworded

Comment: Why are you claiming this so simple????

Comment: This isnt answered anywhere as far as I can see

Comment: Which book(s) are you studying?

Comment: Non-dividend paying assets in the Heston model do have the short rate as instantaneous return, see [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/61931/41821).

Comment: @BobJansen Ive used Stochastic Calculus for Finance II mainly, but have used other standard sources a bit as well

Comment: https://fermatslastspreadsheet.com/2012/01/24/what-is-the-risk-neutral-measure/ This sources gets closest to my desired answer. "A footnote: how exactly do my quants derive the risk neutral probabilities from prices?" The problem with this footnote is that it doesnt give any justification as to WHY it works.

Comment: And odw = $\sigma dW$?

Comment: @BobJansen edited now

Comment: I still think its pretty non trivial as to why certain models can be calibrated to market and we just say those parameters are risk neutral

Comment: Anyone?????????

Comment: Risk neutrality means discounted non dividend paying asset prices are martingales under the model dynamics, nothing more. Any model that satisfies this has risk neutral dynamics. If in addition the model free parameters are calibrated to market (e.g. vol of vol, vol mean rev, vol/spot correl calibrated to options prices in the Heston model) then you have risk neutral dynamics calibrated to market.

Comment: @AntoineConze Ok, but risk neutrality implies that all paths have the same expected path. So how can calibrating to one path, mean all other paths have the same expected value? We only calibrate on one path

Comment: Can you elaborate on "We only calibrate on one path" as I do not understand what you mean by that.

Comment: well one stock market price chart through time only represents one possible path from the start point

Comment: Consider a diffusion model for a stock, no dividends. You can use a single historical path to estimate volatility, but that has nothing to do with risk neutrality. The risk neutral condition for the model dynamics under the risk neutral measure is that the stock price drift is always equal to the instantaneous rate, nothing more.

Comment: But in the models the stock price drift isnt r? Also how can you be so sure that just because the price process discounted is a martingale that this means risk neutral?

Comment: How can you even be sure that a model you are constructing is likely to be a martingale??

Comment: Sorry but the whole framework of this just isnt clicking in my head

Comment: The definition of a risk neutral measure $\mathbb{P}$ is that discounted non dividend paying asset prices are martingales under $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: @AntoineConze did you mean both p there?

Comment: See here http://atmif.com/papers/rn.pdf under Market Calibration "Many authors in the literature simply claim that they are using the "risk neutral" pricing measure when doing market calibrations." How can they just claim this?

Comment: I really dont see why this is a trivial or stupid question and is getting downvoted?

Comment: In calibration, you seek model parameters to minimise the weighted sum of squared pricing errors, the difference between market prices and model prices (it's a bit like GMM, in case you have an econometrics background). You compute these model prices using risk-neutral pricing: expected payoff under $\mathbb{Q}$ and discounted at $r$. Thus, you find the parameters corresponding to that pricing approach (i.e. the risk-neutral parameters). They are useless to predict future price trajectories, but are more than sufficient for pricing (exotic) derivatives .

Comment: Any calibration using the current market price of derivatives will be a risk neutral calibration, because all derivatives are priced in a risk neutral world. The Heston model does not NEED to be risk neutral, but by calibrating on assets priced under a risk neutral framework, you back out a risk neutral rate of drift from your no arbitrage requirement. This is juxtaposed with time series calibration (historical), which would give real world parameters.

Comment: @Mild_Thornberry "because all derivatives are priced in a risk neutral world". How can you say this? If you are saying this, why do you say the Heston model doesnt need to risk neutral? How does calibrating the heston model give you risk neutral drift exactly?

Comment: I say it because it’s true? In all seriousness, just do a Google search “are derivatives risk neutral?”. It’s fundamental to our understanding of derivative pricing. My point is that if you calibrate your Heston model using risk neutral assets, your parameters will be risk neutral. The Heston model itself only needs an asset drift, but it’s how you calibrate your parameters that gets you to a risk free drift.

Comment: @Kevin your explanation isnt clear to me as to why the parameters are risk neutral? whats causing it?

Comment: @Trajan how do you value options? their price is $e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\max\{S_T-K,0\}]$. Thus, the option price depends on the risk neutral distribution ($\mathbb{Q}$) only. You calibrate the model (= find parameters) such that the model prices ($e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\max\{S_T-K,0\}]$) come close to market prices. Thus, the found parameters correspond to $\mathbb{Q}$, which we call risk-neutral

Comment: @Mild_Thornberry when i googled that essentially I got the answer that because derivatives can be replicated we dont care about the risk preferences of the agents in the transaction

Comment: @Kevin but how do know a model will suitable? Also how do you know that the found parameters will correspond to Q?

Comment: @Trajan you never know the perfect **model**. That's why there are dozens of different models, each with their own strengths and weaknesses. Whether a model is suitable depends on whether you want to price short term equity options or long term swaptions etc. So you look at the properties of the model (mean reversion etc.) Once you picked some models that you can justify to your clients, you then calibrate that model to find the parameters that reproduce current market prices.

Comment: @Kevin so are you saying you can take model of the underlying, calibrate market it to the current market, and back out the risk neutral parameters? It still doesnt make sense to me because up until now we havent thought about a derivative. For instance the Vasicek model is a model of the short rate, no derivative yet

Comment: Calibration means to match theoretical model prices of (typically) vanilla options with observed market prices of (typically) vanilla options. You do not use the value of the underlying for the calibration. Calibration is about fitting a model (say Heston) to option prices. The Vasicek model is for the short rate, yes. But it is used to price bond, bond options, caps etc. You find the Vasicek parameters to reproduce the market prices of these instruments. The short rate itself is unobservable anyway.

Comment: @Kevin do you know of any good sources about calibrating these models? I dont think books like Shreve cover calibration

Comment: @Trajan I like [Hirsa's book](https://www.routledge.com/Computational-Methods-in-Finance/Hirsa/p/book/9781439829578). What questions do you have left?

Comment: @Kevin none right now, ill need to look into some things now to try and understand this all

Comment: @Trajan Let me know if more questions come up. It may not be simple to wrap one's head around these questions when one encounters them the first time!

Comment: Edited question

Comment: @Trajan Sorry, I didn't see you responded to my comment. That's why we begin comments with the 'at' symbol. I'll respond to the updated question in a proper answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two parts to your question which I try to answer separately. The first one is about what calibration actually is whereas the second question deals with risk-neutral pricing.

As an example, we can use any model. I continuously refer to the stochastic volatility model from [Heston (1993)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/6/2/327/1574747) as an example for equity options. Any thoughts equally apply to other models or asset classes (think of interest rate derivatives and short rate models). The Heston model for a stock price $S_t$ reads as
\begin{align*}
\text{d}S_t&=\mu S_t\text{d}t+\sqrt{v_t}S_t\text{d}W_S, \\
\text{d}v_t&= \kappa(\theta-v_t)\text{d}t+\xi\sqrt{v_t}\text{d}W_v,
\end{align*}
where $\text{d}W_S\text{d}W_v=\rho\text{d}t$. Thus, there are five model parameters ($\mu,\kappa,\theta,\xi,\rho$).

### Estimation and Calibration

*Estimation finds the real-world distribution of stock returns; calibration aims to parametrise the risk-neutral distribution. To this end, estimation uses historical observations whereas calibration uses observed market prices. Estimation is commonly used for risk management (e.g., value-at-risk) whereas calibration is used for pricing/hedging/trading derivatives.*

Let's begin with **estimation**: Take historical returns of the S&P 500 index and compute the (log-)likelihood function from the Heston model to find the parameters that are most likely to have given rise to the given sample of stock returns (This is called [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20maximum%20likelihood%20estimation,observed%20data%20is%20most%20probable.)). A generalisation is [GMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments) which compares sample moments from the data with moments implied by the model and finds the parameters that minimise the difference between the two. **Intuitively, you seek parameters such that simulations of the model yield sample paths that look very similar to the actual data** you observe in financial markets. In particular, this includes that asset prices grow at same rate $\mu$ that reflects the systematic risk of that asset. You could such a model for forecasting.

Let's turn to **calibration**: Take current market prices for S&P vanilla call and put options. Using the closed-form solution for option prices in the Heston model, **you now seek model parameters which minimise the (squared) difference between observed market prices and implied model prices.** This time, you don't care about historical return data. You only take yesterday's option prices and you match your model with these prices. If you calibrate a short rate model, you can use the prices of zero bonds, bond options, caps etc. Your choice of calibration instruments should match your intended application of the model. Because these instruments are priced using a risk-neutral framework (see below), the calibrated parameters correspond to the $\mathbb{Q}$ measure in which assets are assumed to grow at rate $r$ (and not $\mu$). Thus, these parameters must not be used for forecasting! These parameters, instead, are used for valuing other (complex) derivatives.

Two points are in order

- There are two different time horizons: Estimation requires a (long) time series of returns. Calibration requires price data from one single day.
- In practice, there are many subtitles when one wants to implement estimation or calibration in practice: How to discretise a continuous time model? What moments to match for GMM? How to weight different market prices? How to clean options data? Calibrate to prices or implied volatilities, etc.

### Pricing and Risk-Neutral Distribution

Option pricing is (almost) always done under the [risk-neutral ($\mathbb{Q}$) measure](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/55251/41821). The value of a European-style call option is computed as discounted expected payoff
\begin{align*}
C=e^{-rT}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}[\max\{S_T-K,0\}].
\end{align*}
The risk-neutral distribution ($\mathbb{Q}$) is necessary such that we can discount at the risk-free rate $r$ (instead of bothering with risk premiums embedded $\mu$). The idea is that the $\mathbb{P}$ distribution (i.e., real stock price movements) contains these risk premiums which are extremely difficult to identify. The risk-neutral pricing framework allows us to avoid all of this and arrive at the same option prices while pretending everyone is risk-neutral (we pretend that $\mu=r$).

The crux is that we do not need to know $\mu$ to price options. When we calibrate a model, we minimise the difference between market prices and model prices. These model prices are computed using the risk-neutral framework (all option prices are). Thus, you only recover the risk-neutral distribution from option prices, see also [Breeden and Litzenberger (1978)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2352653?seq=1). But that's no problem. We only need that risk-neutral distribution to value derivatives.

The $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ distribution are linked via the [stochastic discount factor](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63268/41821) (or pricing kernel) which is just a scaled Radon-Nikodym derivative (change of measure via Girsanov's theorem). Thus, the $\mathbb{P}$ parameters and the $\mathbb{Q}$ parameters are also linked, using the risk premiums embedded in the pricing kernel, see [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/61931/41821). Thus, if we knew the true SDF and the true $\mathbb{Q}$ parameters, we could recover the true $\mathbb{P}$ parameters.

Comment: This is a great answer. Can you suggest how I could rephrase my question in order to get it undownvoted? I feel your answer deserves better!

Comment: @Trajan Thank you very much. Firstly, I'm glad you like the answer! I think a lot of the confusion in the comments came from the fact that when the term "calibration" was used, no one was thinking about the difference to estimation and the difference between fitting $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ parameters. But I think it became clear in the comments (to me at least).

Comment: None of the textbooks Ive read cover estimation or calibration

Comment: @Trajan I think I've previously mentioned the book from [Hirsa](https://www.routledge.com/Computational-Methods-in-Finance/Hirsa/p/book/9781439829578)? I have seen many other textbooks discussing the topic. In the end, calibration is only a least squares fit. But you're right. Standard introductions like Shreve or Hull don't cover _how_ to find model parameters. These books are more concerned with teaching the basic tools. But if you switch to applications, you find a lot of material about calibration and estimation. Please let me know if you have more questions/if I can add to my answer